# GStreamer Editing Services freezes when transitions are added

Tags: video, ubuntu, video-processing, gstreamer

I'm trying to use `Gstreamer`'s [GStreamer Editing Services](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-editing-services/html/index.html) to `concatenate` 2 videos, and to have a `transition` between the two.

This command, which joins 2 segments of the videos together without a transition, works fine:

```
ges-launch-0.10 vshort01.mov 0 5 vshort02.mov 5 5 -r -o file:///tmp/foo.mov
```

Here is the output from it:

```
$ ges-launch-0.10 vshort01.mov 0 5 vshort02.mov 5 5 -r -o file:///tmp/foo.mov
save_path: (null)
load_path: (null)
Adding file:///home/rory/vshort01.mov inpoint:0:00:00.000000000 duration:0:00:05.000000000
Adding file:///home/rory/vshort02.mov inpoint:0:00:05.000000000 duration:0:00:05.000000000
Done
```

If I try to have a short `transition` between the 2 videos with this command, it just hangs.

```
ges-launch-0.10 vshort01.mov 0 5 +transition crossfade 2 vshort02.mov 5 5 -r -o file:///tmp/foo.mov
```

The output, I get is this:

```
save_path: (null)
load_path: (null)
Adding file:///home/rory/vshort01.mov inpoint:0:00:00.000000000 duration:0:00:05.000000000
Adding <transition:crossfade> duration 0:00:02.000000000
Adding file:///home/rory/vshort02.mov inpoint:0:00:05.000000000 duration:0:00:05.000000000
```

And there it hangs. The file `/tmp/foo.mov` stays at 0 bytes, with no CPU activity.

> I am using package `ges0.10-tools` version 0.10.1-1 on ubuntu 11.04 natty. I have tried a freshly built version of gst-editing-services
> from a git clone today `c2668d058501513b734c8a8013a5e78c817712bb`

I tried without the `-r -o …` options (i.e. telling `ges-launch` to display the video, not render it to a file), and the same problems occurred. With the `+transitition`, the window opens (to show the video) showing the first frame of the first video. But the video doesn't play, and there is no CPU usage etc.

How do I get it to make a file and transition between them?

Comment: I haven't solved this problem with GES. Instead I used GStreamer. I have heard that GES might have been fixed to solve this though, so it might work now.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a _programming_ problem.  Unless you have actually written some code, in which case you should be including that in the question.